# SQL Count by Column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

MY Table

[image]

Considering only yellow lines..

I have an output as follows:

[image]

How can I convert this to:

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SONG_ID)) AS PLAY_COUNT,
      CLIENT_ID AS CLIENT_ID 
  FROM `mytable` 
 WHERE PLAY_TS LIKE '%10/08/2016%' 
 GROUP 
    BY CLIENT_ID;
```

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And store dates using a date data type

Comment: Yes, I know. This is just a dry run.

Comment: The perfect time to start then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ot.PLAY_COUNT, COUNT(ot.CLIENT_ID) AS CLIENT_COUNT 
   FROM (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT(mt.SONG_ID)) AS PLAY_COUNT, 
            mt.CLIENT_ID 
         FROM `mytable` AS mt
         WHERE mt.PLAY_TS LIKE '%10/08/2016%' 
         GROUP BY mt.CLIENT_ID) AS ot 
   GROUP BY ot.PLAY_COUNT;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for follow up. I have updated my question. Can you please take a look at it for the best answer?

Comment: Hello, I have updated my answer. I think it will work as you want. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot your where clause. Please see now. Thanks.

Comment: You are just the best! Thanks brother!

Comment: So, last question.. What do 'ot' and 'mt' mean?

Comment: Okay as the last comment, we have a virtual table here, so we needed to give aliases to the inner and the outer (virtual) table. mt = mytable, ot = outer_table for example that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your query into another query:

```
select play_count as distinct_play_count, count(*) as client_count 
from (your_first_query) s1
group by play_count
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for follow up. I have updated my question. Can you please take a look at it for the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us more information, but you can do something like this:

```
SELECT play_count, client_count FROM table
GROUP BY play_count
```

But again you better improve the details of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have shared my query. Please have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PLAY_COUNT, COUNT(CLIENT_ID) AS CLIENT_COUNT
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY PLAY_COUNT
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for follow up. I have updated my question. Can you please take a look at it for the best answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PLAY_COUNT AS DISTINCT_PLAY_COUNT, COUNT(CLIENT_ID) AS CLIENT_COUNT

FROM Table

GROUP BY PLAY_COUNT HAVING COUNT(CLIENT_ID) > 0
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for follow up. I have updated my question. Can you please take a look at it for the best answer?